# Visual Studio 2017 - How to build with attached DLL's (not file)

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

When i build my application on `Visual Studio 2017`, lot's of files will be moved to the `/Release/` directory (see Screenshot):

[image: Example]

How i can prevent this? I don't want hundret of files. Is there a way to attach the depencies/references in the application itself, without copying the DLL and language files with in `/Release/`?

Comment: For the localization Folders (de, fr,es..etc), I am not sure, but for the Dll's you can use Costura -> https://github.com/Fody/Costura this will embed the dlls (and other resources, probably Localization folders too) in to your .exe or .dll final file.
It's quite a lot of work,btw, but once you have everything configured, works like charm.

Comment: Do you compile to `netcoreapp` or `netstandard`?

Comment: What project you use? Maybe you can share some info about project type, framework so that we can check for it. And I wonder if it's a publish folder?

Comment: Any update? And I do wonder if it's a output folder from 'build', I only encounter such situation when publishing a web-app with self-contained option.